# How to translate git command line to tortoiseproc?

Tags: git, command-line, tortoisegit

How does the command line for TortoiseGit's TortoiseProc.exe look like, to achieve this git command?

```
git pull -v --progress origin master
```

Comment: tortoiseproc /command:pull /path:. shows a dialog to specify the remote, branch etc. I want to skip that. /command:"pull -v --progress origin master" ... does not work.

Answer (score 3):

I think TortoiseProc is there to execute any git command line.
Only to allow you to access certain part of [TortoiseGit](http://code.google.com/p/tortoisegit/) GUI.

You can see an example in [Commit with TortoiseGit / TortoiseSVN directly from VisualStudio](http://www.lanwin.de/2009/11/19/commit-with-tortoisegit-tortoisesvn-directly-von-visualstudio/) or in "[Executing TortoiseGit from the command line](http://ayende.com/blog/4749/executing-tortoisegit-from-the-command-line)":
In each case, a GUI pops up when the tortoiseProc command is called.

Answer (score 1):

If you already knows the corresponding git command line, why don't you run in bash directly?
To make it easy to run bash with current directory, you may run msysgit setup and tick the context menu item in setup options.